# Is it possible to set a Default App on Server 2016 being used for RDS that isn't installed on the server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, rds, microsoft

I have an RDS server setup to run a single LOB app remotely.

This LOB app has links to documents like .msg files and .pdf files.  When a user running the remote app tries to open a file via the remote LOB app, it's looking to the server to see what the default program is to open that with.

For PDF's this isn't a big deal.  I have Adobe Reader installed on the RDS server and on the local machine, and PDFs open just fine.

However with email files (.msg) - there is no program (like Outlook) on the server and so the local machine doesn't know how to open these (even though Outlook is on the local machine).

Comment: What's the purpose of these .msg files? How does the application use them? If the user needs only to read these files, you can associate the file extension with Notepad on the server and they'll open in Notepad.

Comment: Or as Workaround, Thunderbird can do this also ;) and @joeqwerty yes but i belive they are unable to understand whats inside. Specially when decoded via BASE64

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Because you are running the LOB app as a RemoteApp, when it is used to open a file on the Remote Desktop Server, it is that server that must have the proper software to open the file. Depending on your environment it may be helpful to install Outlook (you can install only Outlook with the click to run installer with a custom configuration xml file) and configure the installation of Outlook to use Shared Computer Activation for the license activation.